# Adding Cordova Plugins to Platypi Project

Tags: cordova, cross-platform

How can I add cordova plugins to a Platypi project?

I'm starting out with the new mobile development framework Platypi.

I would like to add a Cordova plug-in to the project specifically to scan QR codes.

I've tried adding the plugin from the command line with the following command, but it errors with '*Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.*'

```
cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the [CLI](https://github.com/Platypi/platypi-cli) you can simply open the Gruntfile.js in the root project directory and add 'com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner' to the [cordovacli:add_plugins](https://github.com/csantanapr/grunt-cordovacli) grunt task. Then you can remove the cordova folder and run `grunt setup-cordova` again. Alternatively, if you've already modified your project files for cordova you can run `grunt cordovacli:add_plugins` to avoid overwriting anything.